# Disable part of validation (annotations) in PHP Eclipse Photon

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I just installed newest version of Eclipse for PHP, its Photon Release (4.8.0).
The main problem is that by default this IDE tries to validate each file, so everywhere there is a vast amount of errors as unresolved imports, unknown types and classes and more, which I cant get rid of, and they make code flashing in reds and orange underscores.

Facts:

- Version of Eclipse: Photon Release (4.8.0)
- I'm connecting with remote files via Remote System Explorer
- I **don't have Eclipse project** (I hope it's not important fact beacuse this is very large system and indexing all files by Eclipse could take a lot - I tried it in earlier version of Eclipse and gave up after 12 hours)
- In previous version of Eclipse (I don't remember exact number) I had same configuration and disabling some of unwanted validations was possible

What I tried:

- Go to `Project > Properties > Validation` and disable everything
- Go to `Window > Preferences > PHP > Validation > Errors/Warnings` and this is what **would solve the problem** as those "Semantics checks" listed there is exacly what I would like to disable. Except that any changes here are ignored by IDE...
- Go to `Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text editors > Annotations` and disable error and warning annotations. Yes it works. But also it disable **all** notifications eg. syntax errors, which is not acceptable solution.

### edit: (solution)

Solution offered by @howlger works, but under one condition.

If you don't have PHP project in Eclipse and don't want to index all your files, you can go to `Project > Properties > Project Natures` and add `PHP Properties`. Looks like after this Eclipse started to interpret all my remote folder from Remote System Explorer as PHP project and now settings for PHP projects apply to those files.

After that in `Project > Properties` the `PHP` tab showed up where I followed @howlger instructions to fix problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the ***Build Path*** (which is by default the project folder) for that:

***Project > Properties: PHP > Source Paths > Build Path***